# Self signed client certificate does not reach server application

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api2, owin, azure-service-fabric, self-signed

I have the following setup:

- A self signed certificate for development purposes
- An OWIN hosted Web API, deployed on a local Azure Service Fabric Cluster as a ASF service. The Web API uses HTTPS facilitated with the dev certificate in question.
- A simple .net client application that calls the Web API. In that application the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback method is set so it always returns true (since the CA is not trusted)
- Both the client application and the Web API are on the same local development machine. The certificate is installed in that same machine on the "machine store"

Now I am able to make calls to the web api using Fiddler by providing the required client certificate. However when I try to do the same via .net code (be it RestSharp or WebRequest) the client certificate is not present in the RequestContext object on the server side. This result in an Unauthorized response. I do not think the problem is with the client code, the certificate is loaded correctly and assigned to the http client or request. Fiddler shows encrypted tunneling to the server. However the client certificate does not seem to be present at the server side.

I am at a complete loss regarding what am I missing that could cause this behavior. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Install the certificate into the 'Local Machine/Trusted People'.

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to already trust the certificate before it asks. The `CertificateRequest` message that it sends lists the acceptable CAs that can sign the client certificate. If the client certificate's signer isn't in that message, it can't send it.

How you accomplish that in your environment is left as an exercise for the reader. In general now that SSL certificates are available free there is little reason to indulge in the time costs and administrative inconveniences of self-signed certificates. IMHO there wasn't even if you were paying for a CA signature.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem when a service called another service over HTTPS and it couldn't setup a secure connection. My problem was that since the service is running as NETWORK SERVICE, it couldn't find the certificate, because it was looking in the localmachine/my certificate store.

When I was running from my web browser it was working fine because then, my browser found the certificate in the currectuser/my certificate store.

Add the certificate to the machine/my store and see if it helps.